# Need to set a short timeout in JS … How To?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

This is my JS Code:

```
   $('#archive').click(function(){

    $("#intro-page").slideUp(250);
$('#dapper').show();
$('#navigation').show();
$('.picture_holder_thumb').each(function(index) {
$(this).delay(50*index).fadeIn(400);
});
```

And I want to set a short timeout after the sliding up… The Intro-Page slides up, the wrapper (dapper) will be shown and then – Timeout – the .picture_holder_thumb fades in… How to I write this?

Comment: Use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) on the `.picture_holder_thumb`? Or just add a constant to each, `$(this).delay(100+50*index)`?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.slideUp()` method has a callback available when the animation completes.

`.slideUp([duration] [, complete])`

So,

```
$('#archive').click(function() {
    $("#intro-page").slideUp(250, function() {
        $('#navigation').show();
        $('.picture_holder_thumb').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(50 * index).fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
    $('#dapper').show();
});
```

http://jqapi.com/#p=slideUp